# Rechange hotkey from keyboard to mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, multitasking-view

If press "Win+W" or "Win+A", it opens a multitasking view. How rechange this hotkey to mouse key? Exp "LeftClick + RightClick" or "Middle Button + Right".

Answer (score 1):

After lots and lots of digging, I found the answer — for me, at least! I hope this helps someone else who became addicted to the ease of use brought by combining Mac OS's Exposé and a five-buttoned mouse...

Firstly, I set up `xbindkeys` using the information here: https://askubuntu.com/a/246849/777016

Specifically, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation x11-utils
```

Then I used `xev | grep -A2 ButtonPress` to figure out that my middle (mouse-wheel) button was button number 2.

Then I created the xbindkeys config file:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Then I edited the file `$HOME/.xbindkeysrc` using nano, to add the following lines:

```
"dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:1"
b:2
```

You'll need to log out and then log back in for the changes to take effect.

The number after `b:` is the mouse button number as reported by `xev`.

I got the command to invoke multitasking view from this answer: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/11766/13212 — it wasn't exactly what I wanted, as I'd prefer "show all windows" to "multitasking view" but it's near enough. If anyone knows the commands to invoke other windowing features, please let me know!

You can also add those lines a second time but with `+ Release` on the end, if you want to be able to hold the button down and have the view revert on release. Sadly, to change windows you must click on it with the left button — you can't hold then release the middle button over the window you want, like with Mac OS's Exposé.