# How can I get multitasking / multiple workspaces to function in Loki?

Tags: gala, multitasking-view

Multitasking doesn't work for me, using Loki. I've tried three fresh installs -- no joy. Everything else works great.

When I go to "multitasking view," I see only a single window, with no apps open on it. There's just the one icon below the window, with a "+" on it. But it doesn't do anything.

When I click in that single window, I just go back to the workspace in use. All the app windows reappear on it.

I had Freya installed on this machine before and multitasking worked fine.

I'm not happy about this, because I had gotten so used to the excellent way elementary handles multiple workspace.

Comment: Just a test: what happens if you run `dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:1` in Terminal?

Comment: It causes a blank workspace to appear, with the "+" button below to add another. However, open app windows don't appear on this workspace. It's blank -- just the background image. This is the same thing that happens when I click on the "Multitasking View" icon in the dock. The workspace that pops up is empty, and (presumably because the existing one is empty?) I can't add another. In both cases, clicking on the "+" button does nothing.

Comment: If you open some apps in the first WorkSpace, and then press `WinKey` + ➡ (or `⌘` +  ➡ ), does the view shift to a new empty WorkSpace?

Comment: No it doesn't. The window just jogs briefly in the opposite direction, and then pops back. WinKey + ⇩ does show the workspace switcher. But then so does clicking on the Multitasking View icon in the dock. 

I said above the clicking the "+" button doesn't do anything, but it does elicit a little popping sound.

Comment: This sounds like a bug encountered a while ago, where elementary could not determine the primary display correctly, and not being able to determine the screen for the new Workspace. This was particularly true when using more than one displays. So, please check if the current display is set to primary (System Settings -> Displays -> Click on the small star in the left upper corner of the display), reboot and verify. Also, another way to create a new WorkSpace is by right-clicking the menu bar of an elementary app (Files, Mail, Videos, System Settings...) and select "Move to Workspace Right".

Comment: Also, just to be safe, check and install updates: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Yes! That's it! (The primary display setting.) Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I will repost that comment as an answer now, in case someone stumbles over this issue again. Make sure to mark the question as solved. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: running
    `dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:1`  in Terminal issues the same dissatisfactory result.

EDIT: pressing `WinKey` + `➡` does not shift the view to new WorkSpace

This sounds like a bug encountered a while ago, where elementary could not determine the primary display correctly, and not being able to determine the screen for the new Workspace. This was particularly true when using more than one displays.
SOLUTION: check if the current display is set to primary
System Settings -> Displays -> Click on the small star in the left upper corner of the display, reboot and verify.
 [image: Primary Display set to default]

Comment: Thanks for providing that ```dbus-send``` command, it was just what I needed! (Well, almost.) Do you know how I might find other windowing commands? I used your command here, as I wanted to have the "show all windows" view invoked by the middle mouse button (i.e. by pressing the mouse wheel) https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4463/rechange-hotkey-from-keyboard-to-mouse/14321

Comment: Here's something that might help: https://gist.github.com/AnderRasoVazquez/3e574e093d7f915e2a99507a18925434